# iOS: scheduling notifications appear at original time and scheduled time

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification

I have a question regarding push notifications. We are implementing a feature where the user is able to schedule notifications. I have managed to get the scheduling working. The problem is they still receive the original notification. The one that comes in at 11am is received in this function *UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification* when app is in foreground. The problem is how to invoke *UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification* when app is in background

**Scenario**:

The notifications are supposed to come in at 11am

**Problem**

If i set the time to 12pm
I get the notification at 11am and 12pm

The body for sending the notification looks like this

```
{
    "to" : "FCM Token",
 "notification" : {
     "body" : "Body of Your Notification",
     "title": "Title of Your Notification"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because the original notification is scheduled at 11pm, you need to remove any pending notifications and then schedule one:

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificat‌​ionRequests()
```

Also, please include your scheduling mechanism, I'd love to have a look!

Comment: before scheduling a new one

Comment: It didn't work. The notification is still received when the app is in background. My desired result is that even when the app is in background and a notification is sent, that first it should be delivered at the users specified time

Comment: @grace please include the scheduling mechanism. It has something to do with it

Comment: I have a textfield in where the user sets time. I save the times in user default. In this method  UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, I save the notification sent, i.e the body and title. I then do a check to find if the user defaults earlier contains values. If it does I create a local notification, with the saved notification values.
This works in foreground but in background it doesn't do the check.